# Why to use project scripts instead cli global scripts?

Tags: npm, scripting, command-line-interface, package.json

Why it's convenient to create scripts on the `package.json` of a project, instead of using the same script via the CLIs or any other tools that you have installed locally?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the scripts in package.json are version controlled with your source code, so they're available to anyone using/forking that package.